# Eclipse plugin for spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, ide, eclipse-plugin

IDEA allow to find bean definition, declared in xml, right from Java code. For example if I've got interface `SomeIntrfaceImpl` IDEA allow me to find out instances of `SomeIntrfaceImpl` in `.xml` contextes files, pointing me to .xml file to line of code where bean is created

Is there any Eclipse plugin, that allow me to do the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is different Eclipse provided by SpringFramework makers itself. They have extended the eclipse to provide easy development for Spring web application and other products like Spring ROO also.

Its is called SpringSourceToolSuit. You can download its latest version from [here](http://www.springsource.org/springsource-tool-suite-download) after providing some basic information about you asked in a form there.

Its the best IDE to develop Spring applications. I am currently using it.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.